# The result of a query returns the same value for COLUMN_NAME from an Entity Framework query, which doesn't make sense

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I've been struggling with this problem for days. A colleague wrote a LINQ query against a SQL Server view that he also created, which returns 18 rows for the table name he's filtering on.

The view he created uses the system view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. The weird thing is that when the LINQ query returns the result, all the values for the `COLUMN_NAME` are `ID`.

However, when I run a `SELECT` against the same view, all the `COLUMN_NAMES` are different. I do not understand why there's a discrepancy.

Here's the SQL Server view:

```sql
CREATE view [Core].[vwDataDictionary] 
AS
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by A.[TABLE_CATALOG]) AS [ID]   
        ,A.[TABLE_CATALOG]
        ,A.[TABLE_SCHEMA]
        ,A.[TABLE_NAME]
        ,A.[COLUMN_NAME]
        ,[ORDINAL_POSITION]
        ,[COLUMN_DEFAULT]
        ,[IS_NULLABLE]
        ,[DATA_TYPE]
        ,[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH]
        ,[CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH]
        ,[NUMERIC_PRECISION]
        ,[NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX]
        ,[NUMERIC_SCALE]
        ,[DATETIME_PRECISION]
        ,[CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG]
        ,[CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA]
        ,[CHARACTER_SET_NAME]
        ,[COLLATION_CATALOG]
        ,[COLLATION_SCHEMA]
        ,[COLLATION_NAME]
        ,[DOMAIN_CATALOG]
        ,[DOMAIN_SCHEMA]
        ,[DOMAIN_NAME]
        ,B.[CONSTRAINT_NAME]
        ,C.[CONSTRAINT_TYPE]
    FROM 
        [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] AS A
    LEFT JOIN 
        [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE] AS B ON A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME 
                                                            AND A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
    LEFT JOIN
        [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS] AS C ON B.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE 
        A.[TABLE_SCHEMA] = 'App'
```

He tends to declare a global DbContext to use. I thought that was the problem, so I changed the code only slightly to use a local DbContext. Unfortunately, it didn't help as the changes I made are identical to what his code made.

With only that difference, the rest of this C# code is his:

```cs
using (var ctx = new CoreFrameworkEntities())
{
    var dd_fields_query = ctx.vwDataDictionaries.Where(d => d.TABLE_NAME == CurrentTableName);
    var dd_fields_query_list = dd_fields_query.ToList();

    foreach (var item in dd_fields_query_list)
    {
        string col_name = "";

        foreach (var camel in SplitCamelCase(item.COLUMN_NAME))
        {
            col_name = col_name + camel + " ";
        }

        col_name = col_name.Replace("_", "").Trim();

        if (item.COLUMN_NAME == "ID")
        {
            col_name = "ID";
        }
        else if (item.COLUMN_NAME == "InstrumentID")
        {
            col_name = "Instrument ID";
        }
        else if (item.COLUMN_NAME.EndsWith("ID"))
        {
            col_name = item.COLUMN_NAME.Split('I')[0] + " ID";
        }

        KeyValuePair<vwDataDictionary, string> kvp = new KeyValuePair<vwDataDictionary, string>(item, col_name);
        TableFields.Add(kvp);
    }
}
```

And here's the `SELECT` I wrote, to compare the results against what the LINQ query is yielding:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Core.vwDataDictionary
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Proficiency'
```

So, why is it that the LINQ query returns 18 rows, all with a value of "ID", whereas the `SELECT` returns 18 rows all with the correct column names for the `Proficiency` table?

Comment: Do you need a left outer join?

Comment: What is the SQL query being transmitted from the LINQ Query? Consider using LINQPad to debug the query. What is the result of running that SQL Query?

Comment: @jdweng The view has a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @NetMage :What happens if right side is null?

Comment: I don't know why the SQL View uses a LEFT JOIN. @NetMage great suggestion about using LINQPad. I'll give that a try now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle problem with *views* when used from Entity Framework.

If you have a table with EF, you need to have a **primary key** to uniquely identify each row. Typically, that's a single column, e.g. an `ID` or something like that.

With a view, you don't have the concept of a "primary key" - the view just contains some columns from some tables.

So when EF maps a view, it cannot find a primary key - and therefore, it will use *all non-nullable columns* from the view as "substitute" primary key.

When EF now reads the data, it will get all the columns and create an in-memory object representing that row. If EF now later on reads another row from the database **where those non-nullable columns** that make up the *substitute PK* of your view are the same - then it'll think: "gee, I already have that row" and just add another copy of the same object into your result set.

So in this case, in the end you might end up having 18 identical rows in your **EF result set** - even though the SQL Server output properly shows different data. ......

**UPDATE:** as a possible solution, you could try to tap in the `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` catalog views which offer "better" columns - non-nullable ones, that aren't all the same for each column....

Try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [Core].[vwDataDictionary] 
AS
    SELECT 
        t.Name,
        t.object_id,
        c.Name,
        c.column_id
        -- possibly later more columns here....
    FROM
        sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN
        sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. We depend upon that SQL View, so how can we work around that problem with EF?

Comment: Actually isn't that what the first line in the SQL View is supposed to do? `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by A.[TABLE_CATALOG]) AS [ID] `

Comment: I'm wondering if putting in a data annotation of `[Key]` into the model class for vwDataDictionary would resolve this issue? At the moment it's just `public long? ID {get; set;}`

Comment: The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view only has the  `TABLE_NAME` which is non-nullable - and that value is the same for each of those rows. You might want to check out whether you can rewrite your view to use the SQL Server specific  `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` catalog views - those have more non-nullable columns (like `object_id` and `column_Id`) which should provide uniqueness for rows

Comment: The `ROW_NUMBER()` is probably not considered "non-nullable" and thus won't be used in the "substitute" PK for the view ....

Comment: I'll consider that @marc_s. One thing that bothers me, this code has been in place literally for months, without raising this problem. Why would it cause a problem now?

Comment: I've just tried putting in a `[Key]` data annotation on the ID property. I changed ID from a nullable long to a long. Then I removed the `[Key]` attribute from the TABLE_NAME property. That has finally worked!!! I want to thank you all for your great feedback. You all showed me the direction I needed to go in, to resolve this issue.

Comment: BTW, I think I might know why it suddenly now started to cause problems, whereas before it wasn't. We used to use EF's EDMX files. (We're working with EF 6.) I've been moving us away from EDMX to code first. So, the EF generated model class probably did what it thought was best for the given SQL View. By putting in the `[Key]` attribute on ID (and removing it from TABLE_NAME) I told it what it should consider a primary key.

Comment: @Rod: that sounds reasonable, indeed. Glad you were able to fix this!

Comment: I think you are missing something from "If EF now later on reads another row" like with the same values?

Comment: @NetMage: with the same values in the *columns that make up the substitute primary key* - yes